# Where to find/use Python's API?

Tags: java, python, documentation

So this isn't really a programming question, but it applies and I can't really find a solution elsewhere.

So in java, there is a beautifully documented API provided by Oracle. It's really easy to find the exact object you need, all it's variables, constructors, and methods. I found python's documentation, but it really didn't help. It only gives examples, which is nice, but I want to be able to look up all the available information about any object like I can with java.

So the question is, does it exist? I've looked around the internet, found some pretty decent tools, but nothing as well documented as the java api.

Comment: the python docs are extensive, https://www.python.org/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It only gives examples.

I don't know what documentation you're looking at. [This has every module, object, class, and function in the Python standard API listed, documented, and explained.](https://docs.python.org/2/) You were probably looking at the tutorial part of the documentation.

Comment: Okay, let me be more specific. I am working with tkinter. Say I want to look at a specific class called Button, which is a type Widget. I can't find the page that gives me all the details for Button.

Comment: Tk isn't the Python Standard library. [It's just a GUI toolkit which is included in Python.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)) You can find that information [right here, in the Tk documentation.](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/)